# Construct string from its permutation with least jumps back

Tags: python, string, algorithm, optimization, matching

Find a polynomial time algorithm or prove np-hardness for the following problem:

Given two strings `s1=a1, a2,...,ak` and `s2=b1,...,bk,` where `s2` is a random permutation of `s1`.

We now want to build `s1` out of `s2`. A construction works as follows:

Pick a letter from `s2`, that is equal to `a1` and remove it.

Proceed, with letter `a2` and remove it and so on, until `s2` is empty.

Note, that the same letter can occur multiple times in `s2`. Let `C = c1, c2,...,ck` be the constructed sequence, so that `C = s1`. We define `l` to be the number of times we need to jump back in `s2` to pick the next letter.

For example, if we chose `c3` and `c4`, but the index of `c4` in the original `s2` is smaller than the index of `c3` in the original `s2`, we increment `l` by one.

Our task is, to find the optimum sequence, so that `l` is minimal. If we are given `s1=abac` and `s2=acab` for example, the output has to be 1, since we can pick the second "a" from `s2`, then choose "b", then jump back and pick the first "a", then add "c".

I don't know how to solve this problem in polynomial time. I thought maybe there is some way to calculate a perfect matching and read of the optimal sequence, but I am not sure. So far, I have only an exponential algorithm.

The exponential algorithm looks as follows (not sure if it is correct, don't know how to test it):

```
def solvenaive(s1, s2, curr_ind):
    if len(s1) == 0:
        return 0
    first_s1 = s1[0]
    
    vorkommen = findOccurrences(s2, first_s1)
    results = []

    for i in vorkommen:
        new_s1 = s1[1:]
        new_s2 = stringPop(s2, i)
        res = solvenaive(new_s1, new_s2, i)
        
        if curr_ind > i:
            results.append(res+1)
        else:
            results.append(res)
    
    return min(results)
```

Comment: res being a list, res + 1 won't work, though the general idea of your recursive algorithm seems right. As for testing it, what prevents you from implementing findOcurrences() and stringPop() ?

Comment: @Swifty it does look confusing, but each itarete actually returns a number (min(results)) , so res + 1 will work

Comment: I actually implemented and tested it. But i am not happy with a worst case exponential time algorithm. (Also i don't know, if the results are correct. It works for simple testcases tho)

Comment: Oh indeed; but then I'm not sure the logic will hold; anyway, `vorkommen = [i for i in range(len(s2)) if s2[i]==first_s1]` and `new_s2 = s2[:i] + s2[i+1:]` should do the job. As for the logic, I'd actually return a list, not the min of the list, and replace `res+1` with `[i+1 for i in res]`.

Comment: Your algorithm is halfway branch&bound. You enumerate correctly with the recursion all the possibilities. But you never "cut" any subcomputation. Which is the whole point. That is you should estimate what is the minimum "res" you can reach from a subcall. And stop immediately if that minimum "res" is not smaller than the best res you already got.

Comment: By the way, it would probably be better if your function returned the "path" in addition to the min number of backtracks. And, to expand on @chrslg 's comment, perhaps split 'vorkommen' into 'ahead_indices' (>= curr_ind) and 'backward_indices' (< curr_ind), treat the ahead ones 1st, returning 0 as soon as res = 0, 1 when they're all done if the min res is 1, then threat the backward indices, returning 1 whenever res = 0. I can't see how you can cut more corners, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: From the little I understand, problems that are in NP must be verifiable in polynomial time. I have no proof but my intuition is that we have no exclusive way of verifying any one solution here in polynomial time, short of proving correctness for a general polynomial time solution. This would make this problem outside of NP - and NP hard by definition?

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify my comment on branch&bound, here is my shot.

It is clearly faster than yours (while keeping the "naive" pure python implementation. For example, using immutable strings when we clearly want to "mutate" them :D). Yet, it is still clearly not polynomial. Just a faster exponential.

That is most of the time the case with branch&bound.

```py
import itertools
import random
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

W=10 # Size of a word

# Generate a random word
def randomWord():
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(list("abcdef"),W))

# And a random shuffling of it
def shuffle(s):
    return ''.join(random.sample(s,len(s)))

# Quick'n'dirty implementation of the function you are using
# It would have been better, btw, if you had provided them, as
# needed to create a minimal reproducible example
def findOccurrences(s, c):
    return [pos for pos, char in enumerate(s) if char == c]

def stringPop(s, i):
    return s[:i]+s[i+1:]

# Your function
def solvenaive(s1, s2, curr_ind):
    if len(s1) == 0:
        return 0
    first_s1 = s1[0]
    
    vorkommen = findOccurrences(s2, first_s1)
    results = []

    for i in vorkommen:
        new_s1 = s1[1:]
        new_s2 = stringPop(s2, i)
        res = solvenaive(new_s1, new_s2, i)
        
        if curr_ind > i:
            results.append(res+1)
        else:
            results.append(res)
    
    return min(results)

# Mine. Almost the same.
# But I add 2 parameters
# bestScore which is what we have seen best
# and sofar, a partial score 
def solvecut(s1, s2, curr_ind, bestScore, sofar=0):
    if len(s1)==0: # If we reach a "leaf" of recursion, then
                   # return the score. (sofar is a real score in that case, not a partial)
        return sofar
    # Otherwise, we will recurse... unless it is a lost cause
    if sofar>=bestScore: # No need to try better, we are already over our best
        return 1e9

    first_s1 = s1[0]
    
    vorkommen = findOccurrences(s2, first_s1)


    for i in vorkommen:
        new_s1 = s1[1:] # I let that one here in the loop because I don't want to optimize anything other that my "cuts"
                        # so that improvement are clearly imputable to those cuts
                        # but, obviously that could have been done outside the loop
        new_s2 = stringPop(s2, i)
        if curr_ind>i:
            res=solvecut(new_s1, new_s2, i, bestScore, sofar+1)
        else:
            res=solvecut(new_s1, new_s2, i, bestScore, sofar)

        if res<bestScore:
            bestScore=res

    return bestScore # Sometimes we'll return that just because we did nothing best, but it doesn't matter


# Test if result are the same on some examples

for i in range(20):
    w=randomWord()
    s=shuffle(w)
    sc1=solvenaive(w,s,0)
    sc2=solvecut(w, s, 0, 1e9)
    print(w, s, sc1, sc2)

# Timeit
# Note that timing depends a lot of the word (letter repetition, etc.). So it is important to do them with the same words
# Especially since this is not very fast, so we need to timit with number=1
W=17
w1=randomWord()
s1=shuffle(w1)
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: solvenaive(w1, s1, 0), number=1))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: solvecut(w1, s1, 0, 1e9), number=1))
```

Result

```
cbaaecffae aaebcffcae 2 2
eedeafdffb ffdbeefaed 3 3
aedefdceba adeefcabde 4 4
aaafccaafb aafacaafcb 2 2
eaffdfafef efdffefaaf 2 2
dedbfffbce bcdffbedfe 3 3
fedfcbaeed bedcfaefde 4 4
ffeebfcfab feaebcffbf 3 3
fcdaddbfbf ffddacbfbd 3 3
deffcdeaea eeafdadfce 4 4
cafeeebcdb beaedfbecc 4 4
beefdaeabd edaefbbdea 3 3
ddccbdbdae cdbdbcdead 3 3
bcbababdef decafbbbba 4 4
dfaeceefea edfcefaaee 2 2
abcdcbbdbf fbbadccbdb 4 4
acbedbaefc cbeacaebdf 3 3
aaffacfbde cfaaeafbfd 3 3
edceddebdc dedcecbded 2 2
ecafabdfea fafaeaedbc 3 3
4.060046362923458
0.05187216284684837
```

So we can trust reasonnably that my code returns always the same result as yours.

But timings are nearly 100 times faster.

Yet (I've tried with many W's value, unfortunately it is obvious, despite the randomness), it is still exponential:

```
1 cut=6.040092557668686e-06 
2 cut=8.61193984746933e-06 
3 cut=1.5990110114216805e-05 
4 cut=1.5911879017949104e-05 
5 cut=2.897903323173523e-05 
6 cut=3.5561854019761086e-05 
7 cut=5.8827921748161316e-05 
8 cut=0.00018196692690253258 
9 cut=0.0001191610936075449 
10 cut=0.0002572301309555769 
11 cut=0.0008078841492533684 
12 cut=0.0009584939107298851 
13 cut=0.008062224835157394 
14 cut=0.004587493138387799 
15 cut=0.08773919194936752 
16 cut=0.02209200686775148 
17 cut=0.045466484036296606 
18 cut=0.11209587100893259 
19 cut=0.40787983988411725 
20 cut=2.2789966259151697 
21 cut=1.8927371250465512 
22 cut=1.097903796005994
```

Not smooth... but we can clearly see that it is the log of the timing that is "linear with lot of noise", not the value. So, it is still exponential.

Note also that with some thinking, we should be able to estimate a better minimum bound of the reachable score than sofar (using sofar means that we still always hope that there is a solution without never going back. Which, for example, is impossible if `curr_ind`>0. So we could improve at least by saying that if `curr_ind`>0, then `sofar+1` must be smaller than `bestScore` or else it is no use to try)

Edit: I could no resist and try it.
So here are some slight optimization

```py
def lessNaive(s1, s2, curr_ind, bestScore, sofar):
    if len(s1)==0:
        return sofar
    if sofar>=bestScore or (curr_ind>0 and sofar+1>=bestScore): # No need to try better, we are already over our best
        return 1e9

    first_s1 = s1[0]
    new_s1 = s1[1:]

    for i in range(len(s2)):
        if s2[i]!=first_s1: continue
        new_s2 = stringPop(s2, i)
        if curr_ind>i:
            res=lessNaive(new_s1, new_s2, i, bestScore, sofar+1)
        else:
            res=lessNaive(new_s1, new_s2, i, bestScore, sofar)

        if res<bestScore:
            bestScore=res

    return bestScore # Sometimes we'll return that just because we did nothing best, but it doesn't matter
```

Not much optimization here

1. I put the `new_s1` computation outside the loop
2. I combined the iteration over s2 position with the search for those positions
3. As I said, if `curr_ind>0` then we know that we can't reach less than `sofar+1`. Which is probably the most important optimization, even for just this `+1`, since it cuts whole branches of recursion that were about to equalize the best score.

Timings I got this time

```
11.236965486081317
0.4795242650434375
0.08659004187211394
```

[timings of naive, cut, and now lessNaive]

It was apparently a harder case (since it is for the same W as the previous 4.06/0.051). But the point is, even minor optimization such as this `+1` change by an order of magnitude the timings!
(Yet, it is still exponential. An even smaller exponential, but exponential. The thing with exponential, is that the ratio between two exponential is also exponential! So even going from one exponential to another exponential really worth it. Yet, the smallest exponential of course is still not polynomial)

### Timing update

Follow-up after discussion with Kelly: I ran some other tests. With 6 versions, that is 3 versions already tested (naive, cut, lessnaive), with and without `lru_cache` discussion.

Modus operandi, is that I generate randomly a W=22 word and a shuffle of it. And then ran all 6 code with the same words (that was what I already did before. Because timings are so diverse depending on the randomness of input, it is essential that timing comparison are done with the same input).
Difference with previous timings (outside the `lru_cache` version) is that I kept min/max/average timing ration.

Here are timings after 25 words (not much, but with W=22, and my rather slow computer, that already took 2 days)

```
i=25  fn=solveNaive  t= 120.7  μ=1254.1 ρ=100.00 [100.00:100.00]
i=25  fn=solveNaiveC t= 120.5  μ=1254.0 ρ= 99.86 [ 98.89:102.20]
i=25  fn=solveCut    t=  12.0  μ=   9.1 ρ=  9.95 [  0.00:  9.95]
i=25  fn=solveCutC   t=  12.1  μ=   9.1 ρ= 10.01 [  0.00: 10.01]
i=25  fn=lessNaive   t=   4.0  μ=   2.1 ρ=  3.29 [  0.00:  3.29]
i=25  fn=lessNaiveC  t=   4.0  μ=   2.1 ρ=  3.30 [  0.00:  3.30]
```

`C` suffix mean the function with `lru_cache` decoration.

So, I must say, I don't see the same result as Kelly did.
`t` is timing for each iteration (here, the 25th one only). μ is the average timing (total timing for all 25 examples, divided by 25). Then I compute ratio between the timing for an example, and timing for the same example with 'naive' version (Hence the fact that for 'naive' line, those ratio are always 100%). ρ is the average of those ratio for the 25 examples. And between brackets are the minimum and maximum value of that ratio for those 25 examples.

Conclusion is that

- `lru_cache`, on average, slightly help for 'naive' version. But very slightly only. And not for other versions.
- Timing ratios are on average a x30 factor, not x100 indeed. x100 was lucky. But note that those are also the worst case scenario. Reason is some examples take an awful long time to run, and those are the ones where ratio is least favorable. Yet, it is still a x30 factor. Note that best case scenario is so high that I can measure it (because of my choice to print only 2 decimal places). But that means that best case scenario are scenario where timing of `lessNaive` are less that 0.005% than the 'naive' version. Which means that ratio can be up to x20000 in favor of `lessNaive`. And, again, never less than x30 in favor of `lessNaive`.

So, timings vary wildly indeed. But never to the point where `lessNaive` is slower. Besides, this seems almost impossible, since it is the exact same code, with just some recursion stopped. It could be very slighly slower if it were to fail to cut any recursion at all: they we would pay the cost of the test, with nothing in return. But that test is way less costly than the rest of the code (pop, etc.). Even if in all the 25 examples, we never encounter a case with `lessNaive` is not at least 30 times faster, it may be theoretically possible to build an example where it is slightly slower (an example where no recursion are aborted by line `if sofar>=bestScore or`...) but I don't think 50% slower is possible.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Maybe there is no polytime algorithm. That would be interesting, as the problem seems so simple

Comment: Try decorating `solvenaive` with `@functools.lru_cache(None)`, makes it much faster.

Comment: I get **wildly** varying times when running multiple times. With W=22, the decorated `solvenaive` is sometimes 100x faster than `lessNaive`, and sometimes it's 2x slower. So I think showing timings of single runs is meaningless and rather misleading. Needs more statistics.

Comment: for missing args, yep, indeed. In previous version, those were default arguments. But because I update bestScore, I can't trust default values, so I removed defaults args values. And apparently forgot to correct a call.

Comment: For `lru_cache`, wasn't aware of that function. But if I understand it correctly, it is usefull when you call a function with indentical args. So it is probably more efficient to optimize OP's version than mine (tho it can also optimize mine).

Comment: For timing, I haven't experienced that. Different timings, sure. I've mentioned it myself. But I ran the code on thousand experiments. I never saw 'lessNaive' being slower. Is this before or after you added the decoration to `solveNaive`?

Comment: It was with decorated `solvenaive`. And yeah, I think using it on your solutions helps them as well, but much less. I guess both because they're already faster and because like you said, the additional params make identical calls rarer.

Comment: @KellyBundy yes but it is very tricky to measure the timing correctly: make sure to clear the cache between `%timeit` iterations. Otherwise, it really computes once and then recalls that result every subsequent call by `timeit`)...

Comment: @PierreD Yes, although I removed the `for i in range(20):` loop and the `timeit`s have `number=1`, so I didn't have that issue. I also wouldn't use a larger `number`, I'd instead use multiple different inputs. It should still start with an empty cache each time, otherwise previous uses would likely make it *slower*. What I'd do is put the solution function into an outer function, so the solution function gets a new cache every time. And such an outer function would also allow hiding the extra parameters, ideally the functions should only take the two strings.

Comment: @PierreD `prev`? You mean `curr_ind`? Yes, that needs to be included. To be clear: I'd decorate the solution function, not the outer function.

Comment: @PierreD But yes, none of these speedups answer the question, that's why I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: Regarding the timing update: You must have used the caching incorrectly. If you show the code, I'll have a look.

Comment: Still hoping you'll share it so we can find the mistake...

Answer (score 4):

The main findings in this exploration are:

1. The difficulty is not related to the length of the strings, `n`, but rather on the number of possible paths in `b` that produce `a` (for a given `n`, that can vary from 1 to many). We give a closed form function for that number of paths, `numpaths`, which is the product of the `n_c!` (`factorial(n_c)`), where `n_c` is the number of times character `c` is found in either string.
2. There can therefore be a very large number of such potential solutions.
3. Within that set, there can also be a large number of equivalent solutions (same cost).
4. Deciding if a certain path is optimal (unless its cost is 0) is difficult and requires work.
5. In branch-and-bound approaches, there is a tradeoff among different lower-bounds between their power (how tight the bound is) and the time they take to compute.
6. There is no single solver that dominates all others: some optimizations are fantastic in some settings, and do very poorly in others. Even the `naive_memoized` version of @KellyBundy, which trades unbounded space requirements for time saving, is doing great *on average* for `m=n//2`, less so for `m=isqrt(n)`, and can perform 1000x *slower* than others on pathological cases.

All these are hints (but no proof) that the problem *may* be NP-hard.

---

#### Note

A previous version of this post was making the wrong claim to have proven NP-hardness. We had attempted to formulate the problem as a directed graph, in which minimum-weight Hamiltonian paths corresponded to the solutions we are searching for here.

First, as correctly noted by @KellyBundy and @NiceGuySaysHi, that would have merely proved that we could solve the problem in exponential time. In order to prove NP-hardness, we would have to do the opposite: find a known NP-hard problem and show that we can transform any instance of that problem into ours to solve it while only increasing the input size by a polynomial expression.

Further, as @גלעדברקן rightly pointed out, the graph procedure was wrong too: although it could work with simple examples, larger ones introduced unwanted possible solutions.

So, I stand corrected, and I have removed the graph analysis entirely. What remains are the other parts of the analysis that some people have found interesting.

#### Outline

- Some basic observations

  - distance is not symmetric: `dist(a, b) != dist(b, a)`,
  - distance is the same as distance of reverted strings: `dist(a, b) == dist(r(a), r(b))`, where `r(s) is s[::-1]`.
  - this immediately disqualifies usual string distances (Levenshtein, Jaro, Jaro-Winkler, Hamming, etc.)
- Building some intuition

  - Difficulty is not related to string length: compare:

    `dist('fdombcglihaeknj', 'clbjmohagfdeink')`: single solution; needs no backtracking and takes ~16 µs to find, versus

    `dist('dabacbbcadccbad', 'baccddcaadbbcab')`: 82,944 solutions, 600 of which have the same global minimum (4), typically takes 1000 times longer.
  - What is a good measure of complexity? Expression of the number of paths possible, `numpaths(b)`.
  - 2D representation, `pos` and `wheels` encoding.
  - It is hard to verify if a path is the minimum.
  - It is hard to develop a good lower bound.
  - A few solvers (returning cost and the path found).
  - Timing observations.

#### Basic observations

First a util to generate arbitrary sized problems:

```py
def gen(n, m):
    """Generates a random problem with n chars chosen among m"""
    a = ''.join(np.tile(list(ascii_letters[:m]), n // m + 1)[:n])
    a = shuffle(a)
    b = shuffle(a)
    return a, b

# example
>>> gen(6, 3)
('bcbaca', 'baaccb')
```

Then, we also adopt @chrslg's excellent `lessNaive()` function, with some minor modifications:

```py
HIGHCOST = 1_000_000  # unlikely to ever be reached in our problems
# only for path-returning functions:
HIGHSOL = HIGHCOST, tuple()  # the solution we return when we give up
TERMSOL = (0, tuple())  # leaf solution


def lsn2(a, b, best=HIGHCOST, prev=-1):
    """
    reformulation of `lessNaive()`, eliminating `sofar` and only using `best`
    """
    if not a:
        return 0
    if prev > 0 and best <= 1 or best <= 0:
        return HIGHCOST
    c, a = a[0], a[1:]
    for i, bc in enumerate(b):
        if c != bc:
            continue
        if prev > i:
            res = lsn2(a, stringPop(b, i), best - 1, i) + 1
        else:
            res = lsn2(a, stringPop(b, i), best, i)
        if res < best:
            best = res
    return best
```

Now, we check to see if the distance is symmetric, and a couple of other properties:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    gen(n, (n + 1) // 2)
    for n in range(3, 20)
    for _ in range(100 // n)
], columns=list('ab')).drop_duplicates()

df = df.assign(
    a_b=df.apply(lambda r: lsn2(r.a, r.b), axis=1),
    b_a=df.apply(lambda r: lsn2(r.b, r.a), axis=1),
    ra_rb=df.apply(lambda r: lsn2(r.a[::-1], r.b[::-1]), axis=1),
    a_rb=df.apply(lambda r: lsn2(r.a, r.b[::-1]), axis=1),
    ra_b=df.apply(lambda r: lsn2(r.a[::-1], r.b), axis=1),
).set_index(['a', 'b'])
```

Examples of non-symmetric costs:

```py
>>> df[['a_b', 'b_a']].query('a_b != b_a').reset_index()
                      a                    b  a_b  b_a
0                  bbaa                 abab    1    2
1                  baba                 aabb    2    1
2                 acbba                bacab    1    2
..                  ...                  ...  ...  ...
73  cefibfcjhdahbaedgig  cebfjadidebcihhaggf    7    5
74  hebicjhgfcdfedaagbi  edjcdgcbbfhiaghifea    6    7
75  bifghgecifdaachedbj  ifjfcebadchgeahdgib    6    5
```

However:

```py
cols = [k for k in df.columns if k not in {'a', 'b'}]
equalities = [
    f'{i} == {j}' for i, j in permutations(cols, 2)
    if (df[i] == df[j]).all() and i < j
]
>>> equalities
['a_b == ra_rb', 'a_rb == ra_b']
```

**⇒ `dist(a, b) != dist(b, a)`, but `dist(a, b) == dist(reverse(a), reverse(b))`**.

That immediately disqualifies most usual string distances (Levenshtein, Jaro, Jaro-Winkler, Hamming, etc.) as these are symmetric.

#### Building some intuition

The first thing to observe is that the difficulty of finding a solution is not dependent on `n`, the size of the strings.  When there are no character repetitions, no matter how large `n` is, there is only a single possible path.

Instead, the primary measure of difficulty is the number of permutations available for each character position.

Let us illustrate with possibly the most inefficient solver: one that iterates through all the possible permutations. Note that this can also be used to spot-check the correctness of another solver (by checking that the solution it returns is one of the possible minimum paths). We also introduce an (obvious) cost measure that uses only the path found as input.

But first, let's introduce an encoding of the problem that makes some analyses easier:

```py
def encode(s):
    """encode a string as a dict: {c: i}"""
    d = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        d[c] = d.get(c, tuple()) + (i, )
    return d

def encode_as_wheels(a, b):
    """
    Encodes a problem as: pos, wheels.
    For each character at position `i` in `a`, that character can
    be found in `b` at indices `wheels[pos[i]]`.

    Each wheel is always ordered.

    Example:
        >>> encode_as_wheels('aba', 'baa')
        ((1, 0, 1), ((0,), (1, 2)))
    """
    wheels = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(b):
        wheels[c] = wheels.get(c, tuple()) + (i, )
    rw = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(wheels)}
    pos = tuple(rw[c] for c in a)
    wheels = tuple(wheels.values())
    return pos, wheels
```

With this, here is the "`by_permutation`" solver:

```py
def compute_cost(seq):
    return sum([i > j for i, j in zip(seq, seq[1:])])


def by_permutation(pos, wheels):
    slots = [v for _, v in sorted(encode(pos).items())]
    for val in product(*[permutations(w) for w in wheels]):
        seq = [(i, j) for ii, jj in zip(slots, val) for i, j in zip(ii, jj)]
        seq = [v for _, v in sorted(seq)]
        yield compute_cost(seq), seq
```

Here is a simple example:

```py
>>> list(by_permutation(*encode_as_wheels('abacb', 'bacab')))
[(2, [1, 0, 3, 2, 4]),
 (1, [3, 0, 1, 2, 4]),
 (3, [1, 4, 3, 2, 0]),
 (2, [3, 4, 1, 2, 0])]
```

In this case, there is a single optimal path (`[3, 0, 1, 2, 4]`) with cost 1, two paths with cost 2, and one with cost 3.

Let's compare two problems with `n=15, m=15`, and another with `n=15, m=4`:

```py
a, b = 'fdombcglihaeknj', 'clbjmohagfdeink'
n, m = len(a), len(set(list(a)))
>>> n, m
(15, 15)

sol = list(by_permutation(*encode_as_wheels(a, b)))
best = min(sol)

>>> best
(8, [9, 10, 5, 4, 2, 0, 8, 1, 12, 6, 7, 11, 14, 13, 3])

>>> len(sol)
1
```

By contrast:

```py
a, b = 'dabacbbcadccbad', 'baccddcaadbbcab'
n, m = len(a), len(set(list(a)))
>>> n, m
(15, 4)

sol = list(by_permutation(*encode_as_wheels(a, b)))
best = min(sol)

>>> best
(4, [4, 7, 0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 3, 13, 5, 6, 12, 14, 8, 9])

>>> len(sol)
82944

>>> len([s for s in sol if s[0] == best[0]])
600
```

##### A measure of difficulty

If `n` is not indicative of the difficulty of a problem, then what is?  From the `by_permutation` function above, we see that the number of paths in `b` is:

[image]

where `n_c` is the number of times the char `c` is found in `b`.

It depends only on `b` (or `a`, since `n_c` is the same in each string). We therefore can calculate this in close form:

```py
from math import factorial
from collections import Counter

def numpaths(b):
    cnt = Counter(b)
    np = 1  # no pun intended
    for k in cnt.values():
        np *= factorial(k)
    return np
```

Examples above:

```py
a, b = 'fdombcglihaeknj', 'clbjmohagfdeink'

>>> numpaths(b)
1

a, b = 'dabacbbcadccbad', 'baccddcaadbbcab'

>>> numpaths(b)
82944

>>> numpaths(a)
82944
```

Note however that, when characters are contiguous in `b`, they shouldn't have to be tried in multiple ways. This is explored by some solvers (e.g. `lsn3`), but not by all. So we think that number of paths is a good estimate of the *basic difficulty* of the problem, and of course heuristics (simple or more complex) are there to whittle down that number of paths.

Therefore, this number could be a better measure to use as x-axis for timing measurements. We will, when time permits, revisit the timings section below in light of that number.

##### 2D representation with `pos` and `wheels` encoding

To understand the difficulty, we built `plot_wheels()` (*to be published later*). The interpretation is: each character has its own color, there are dots at `x, y` if the character is present in `a[x]` and `b[y]`. The optimal path found by one solver (default `xlsn2`) is plotted as a black line:

```py
a, b = gen(6, 3)
>>> a, b
('cabbac', 'accabb')

plot_wheels(*encode_as_wheels(a, b))
```

[image]

Let's look at the case earlier where we found 600 equivalent solutions. We also specify the solution solver to be `by_permutation`, so that we can see all the equivalent solutions (all the 600 that have minimum cost):

```py
a, b = 'dabacbbcadccbad', 'baccddcaadbbcab'
plot_wheels(*encode_as_wheels(a, b), sol=by_permutation)
```

[image]

Our main findings so far are:

1. There can be a very large number of potential solutions, because of the combinatorial nature of how they can be generated.
2. Within that set, there can also be a large number of equivalent solutions (same cost).
3. Deciding if a path is optimal (unless its cost is 0) is difficult and requires work.

All these are hints (but no proof) that the problem *may* be NP-hard.

##### Difficulty to decide if a path is minimal

During the fun time I spent writing this answer, I tried a number of optimizations / heuristics that would further eliminate branches. What I found is that it is quite hard to decide if a path is optimal. It is also very easy to develop a seemingly great `lowerbound` that cuts a lot of work and speeds up the search considerably, only to discover later (thanks to `perfplot`'s `equality_check`) that it is wrong, and that there exist corner cases that result in actual paths costing less than the (wrong) lower-bound was stipulating.

Perhaps that very difficulty (to decide if a path is optimal or not may) be an avenue to prove NP-hardness?

##### Solvers

I wrote a few of those. Some are working on `pos, wheels` arguments, others directly on the strings `a`, `b`. Some have powerful backtracking-cutting `lowerbound` estimates, other aim for simplicity (they backtrack much more, but often the net effect is a wash because they have much less work to do for each path).

Here I'll present just one that is quite fast (up to 100x faster than `lessNaive` or `lsn2` in some cases), and happens to also return the path found, in addition to its cost:

```py
def xlsn3(a, b, best=HIGHCOST, prev=-1):
    """
    When encountering consecutive letters in b, no need to backtrack
    """
    mincost = int(prev > 0)
    if a == b:
        return mincost, tuple(range(len(a)))
    if best <= mincost:
        return HIGHSOL
    c, a = a[0], a[1:]
    bestseq = tuple()
    i0 = max(prev, 0)
    j = -2
    for i, bc in chain(enumerate(b[i0:], i0), enumerate(b[:i0])):
        if c != bc:
            continue
        if i - j != 1:
            deltacost = int(prev > i)
            cost, seq = xlsn3(a, stringPop(b, i), best - deltacost, i)
            cost += deltacost
            if cost < best:
                best = cost
                bestseq = (i,) + seq
                if best <= mincost:
                    return best, adjust_seq(bestseq)
        j = i
    return best, adjust_seq(bestseq)

def adjust_seq(seq):
    if len(seq) < 2:
        return seq
    y = seq[0]
    return (y,) + tuple(e + (e >= y) for e in seq[1:])
```

The particularity of this one is an optimization that appears to cut many combinations while being simple: when two or more letters are consecutive in `b`, there is no point trying them in reverse. By only using them in order, we are still guaranteed to find the optimal path, as there can not be any gain "consuming" a high position first and then later a lower one.

Let's look at an example:

```py
b = 'abccbbbbdddea'
a = shuffle(b)
>>> a, b
('baecbddbabcdb', 'abccbbbbdddea')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
plot_wheels(*encode_as_wheels(a, b), sol=by_permutation, ax=axes[0])
plot_wheels(*encode_as_wheels(a, b), sol=xlsn3(a, b), ax=axes[1])
```

[image]

##### Timing

We use the excellent [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) to plot the performance of some algorithms. I only introduced `lsn2` and `xlsn3` in this post. Basically, `lsn2` is the same as @chrlsg's `lessNaive` function (and is almost indistinguishable in perf. plots, so I removed it here). `lsn3` is a cost-only returning cousin of `xlsn3`. There are many other functions that we developed, not presented here, with various heuristics to safely discard sub-branches. Some of these heuristics are typically lower bounds of various complexity, and they allow us to give up on sub branches that won't possibly yield a cost improvement. The tradeoffs are between the strength of the cutoff (how many few recursions do we incur for a given problem) vs the extra time spent calculating the bound itself.

We also add @KellyBundy's LRU cached version of the OP's "naive" solver: [`naive_memoized`](https://tio.run/##ZZHRaoQwEEXf8xXzpqKF1b4UqdAv6A8syxKTkR0wiSRRaH/ejm5wkc5LMpdzJzfJ9BMfzr5/TH5dB@8MDLNV0bkxAJnJ@Qijn@9KqgcKoXEAK2nBu0Hj6Bd1HuoKQlO0Ari@Djb/dhaLXdxMwY0LJraCyeOSHFsRD3URQv2StvIYZ2/hcoiqho6p6@V2SCFJdfvSks@QzU/zcoLP59FQngJdW7qVvFDJYyqg4mQbnAeqQDVAFtDOBr2MbG3OGF@Cka7jlIf@JFKe8xO81YUQe/oMlUapFapeStkr5E0ve611JkKzA6lXTEmFmltkHGUmJk825v@/hNMV6/oH). This reduces time requirement at some space (memory) expense, by simply remembering identical sub-branches that have been explored before in the course of solving a problem. Note the correct implementation of setting up a new cached function inside `naive_memoized`, so that repeated timings don't actually simply remember data from previous runs.

One important point about timing is, the complexity for a given `n` can vary dramatically (as noted above, because the real difficulty comes from the number of permutations possible). Because of this, we repeat the measurements using a number of loops around `perfplot`, and plot the average of those runs.

[image]

**Note about `naive_memoized`**: by trading time for unbounded memory, this solver is doing great *on average* for `m=n//2`, but less so for `m=isqrt(n)` (although on average its slope in the semilog plot is still better).

Further, in some cases it can perform *1000x slower* than `lsn3`. For example:

```py
a, b = 'bbaababaababaaabbba', 'abbabaaababaabbbaab'
tmem = %timeit -o naive_memoized(a, b)
# 51.7 ms ± 188 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

tln3 = %timeit -o lsn3(a, b)
# 49.1 µs ± 41.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

>>> tmem.average / tln3.average
1052.6
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the high quality answer. I agree with Kelly's comment. To show, that the problem is NP-hard, you would need to show, that given any Hamilonian path problem input, you can use my problem to solve it while only increasing the input size polynomial. What you have shown is in fact, that you can solve the problem in exponential time by finding a hamiltonian path.

Comment: Could you include [`naive_memoized`](https://tio.run/##ZZHRaoQwEEXf8xXzpqKF1b4UqdAv6A8syxKTkR0wiSRRaH/ejm5wkc5LMpdzJzfJ9BMfzr5/TH5dB@8MDLNV0bkxAJnJ@Qijn@9KqgcKoXEAK2nBu0Hj6Bd1HuoKQlO0Ari@Djb/dhaLXdxMwY0LJraCyeOSHFsRD3URQv2StvIYZ2/hcoiqho6p6@V2SCFJdfvSks@QzU/zcoLP59FQngJdW7qVvFDJYyqg4mQbnAeqQDVAFtDOBr2MbG3OGF@Cka7jlIf@JFKe8xO81YUQe/oMlUapFapeStkr5E0ve611JkKzA6lXTEmFmltkHGUmJk825v@/hNMV6/oH) in the benchmark? I think it'll be fastest.

Comment: I am confused by your statement that "Finding our solution is equivalent to finding a minimum-weight Hamiltonian path in the graph." For example, in this problem, given `acbba, abacb`, when we are at the first `b` in the path we create, the graph has edges there to both `a` and `b`, but we are only permitted to go to another `b`. And when we are at the second `b` in the path we create, we again have more edges than we are permitted to traverse.

Comment: Can we say that the problems are "equivalent" if the graph edges are restricted *depending on the path history*? If we use the collapsed graph, don't we end up with this issue? And if we use the graph that has nodes defined with their multiple optional positions in the solution, we would not be able to choose them all, so no Hamiltonian. (cc @NiceGuySaysHi)

Comment: Both `b1` and `b2` have edges to `a0` and `a2`, but if our path is so far `a0 -> b1`, we are not permitted to use the edge, `(b1, a2)`, because it doesn't correspond with the original string, which must have a second `b` next in the path. What am I missing?

Comment: I never mentioned returning to b1. I said we are not permitted to go to a2 from b1 even though there is an available edge, because the resulting path must have two `b`s in a row.

Comment: I would believe your claim about equivalence with Hamiltonian if you can show code that checks thousands of random strings and confirms that every Hamiltonian path corresponds with the original string we are trying to match.

Comment: I believe we got lucky with your one example.

Comment: What about "abaa" as a target string? What would prevent one of the Hamiltonians being "aaba", which would not match but be a valid Hamiltonian?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: you are right, and the "collapsed graph" formulation was wrong. I removed the graph analysis entirely.

Comment: @PierreD cool. We have an implicit graph formulation in the branch-and-bound / backtracking implementation, where we get to ignore some parts of the graph. You have a great point about how can we determine if the solution is correct. I can't think of a way without visiting all required paths.

Comment: An interesting sub-question is: "what is the maximum cost for a given `n`, `m`?" Or, more precisely, for a given multiset of wheel lengths (e.g., `(4,3,3)` for `n=10, m=3`). We know that `cost==0` _implies_ `a==b`. But even determining whether cost==1 or more is tricky. Using many examples, it seems that the maximum cost for `n=10, sorted([len(w) for w in wheels]) == [3,3,4]` is 5. Why?

Comment: @PierreD If I'm not mistaken, `s1 = 'abcabcabca'` `s2 = 'cccbbbaaaa'` has those wheel lengths and cost 6.

Comment: @KellyBundy: yes, good example. Still, the decidability of whether a given cost can be improved seems difficult, unless `best == 1` (in which case, it cannot be unless `a == b`). Where I'm going with this is I wonder if there is a way to reduce the problem from 3-SAT.

Answer (score 2):

Since multiple people found [chrslg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74818404/12671057) non-answer useful, I'll post one as well after all. Also just a speed improvement (not the requested "polynomial time or NP hard"), simply memoizing the original solution with [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Benchmark with string length 17, multiple random inputs:

```
result original memoized ratio
4 True  1.6349   0.0034   482
5 True  0.5427   0.0045   120
5 True  2.8031   0.0023  1212
5 True  0.1241   0.0015    82
5 True  0.6741   0.0026   255
4 True  0.3481   0.0018   190
5 True  1.3098   0.0025   529
5 True  1.0044   0.0015   688
5 True  0.2801   0.0012   229
5 True  0.6569   0.0026   257
4 True  0.3757   0.0012   326
4 True  0.1771   0.0051    34
3 True  8.1880   0.0034  2439
4 True  1.3146   0.0049   267
5 True  0.3008   0.0022   139
4 True  2.6785   0.0022  1203
3 True  1.6143   0.0097   167
3 True  1.1957   0.0048   247
4 True 10.2205   0.0037  2735
```

So simply memoizing it made it dozens to thousands of times faster. From sometimes multiple seconds down to a few milliseconds.

With string length 22 (only the memoized version, so ignore the zeros and Falses):

```
result original memoized ratio
3 False  0.0000   0.1776     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0537     0
5 False  0.0000   0.1178     0
4 False  0.0000   0.0360     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0637     0
5 False  0.0000   0.1188     0
4 False  0.0000   0.0929     0
4 False  0.0000   0.2369     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0185     0
5 False  0.0000   0.0393     0
4 False  0.0000   0.2396     0
5 False  0.0000   0.0630     0
5 False  0.0000   0.2074     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0834     0
4 False  0.0000   0.2619     0
5 False  0.0000   0.1232     0
4 False  0.0000   0.3286     0
4 False  0.0000   0.1616     0
4 False  0.0000   0.1822     0
4 False  0.0000   0.1093     0
5 False  0.0000   0.0277     0
4 False  0.0000   0.2417     0
5 False  0.0000   0.0614     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0984     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0072     0
5 False  0.0000   0.1572     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0791     0
5 False  0.0000   0.1145     0
4 False  0.0000   0.0819     0
5 False  0.0000   0.0507     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0620     0
4 False  0.0000   0.2658     0
4 False  0.0000   0.0956     0
5 False  0.0000   0.1937     0
3 False  0.0000   0.0777     0
5 False  0.0000   0.2270     0
4 False  0.0000   0.2641     0
4 False  0.0000   0.0861     0
6 False  0.0000   0.0993     0
```

chrslg reported 1254 seconds for the original here, so the memoized version's ~0.13 seconds is about ~10000 times faster (different computer, though).

With string length 28 we finally see times over a second (I estimate the original would take *weeks* for such an input):

```
result original memoized ratio
5 False  0.0000   1.2373     0
5 False  0.0000   0.1386     0
5 False  0.0000   1.2382     0
5 False  0.0000   1.9010     0
5 False  0.0000   1.2455     0
6 False  0.0000   0.5460     0
6 False  0.0000   1.3230     0
5 False  0.0000   1.0667     0
5 False  0.0000   3.5551     0
5 False  0.0000   3.3685     0
8 False  0.0000   0.2763     0
7 False  0.0000   0.5888     0
5 False  0.0000   0.5947     0
6 False  0.0000   1.3308     0
6 False  0.0000   0.8198     0
6 False  0.0000   1.6232     0
6 False  0.0000   0.3384     0
6 False  0.0000   1.0543     0
5 False  0.0000   1.3115     0
7 False  0.0000   1.6151     0
5 False  0.0000   2.2333     0
6 False  0.0000   1.4533     0
5 False  0.0000   0.8959     0
5 False  0.0000   0.7359     0
```

Code, most taken from chrslg ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VVNb9swDL37VxDrwTbqZrG7oUWwDNtp2GUf2KEYgiBQbLrWakuGJCfriv72jJIcO26B7Tysh1SiyPceHyOlvTeVFJfXrToceNNKZYAbVEbKWgd9QDFRyCYolWzA8Aahj9u1j5adyF3J8ahW3SZneYVBcLNMr@AMvvFfCLIEBnupiiA4gw8oUDGDFPIM/qTAst/f0DaKFwHQn0LTKQFhOPshuYh8wiyvJM9RRy/YNqe6F8nd8iaOLfh7UYy4uurKsubi1grgxlH4GEb6jwSaNa1NSmoUlOqxv3Y8vwtFWHBl7m3HNTYoDDNcCstgKvSO2P297IAphE4TPxV/NNRmVxdQsR3CFlHQhyHLE9iafQK8dCUVK6BVcscLLCxgkwDTVC4QXURCrtCb13DBG1ZTB1RQdDnf1gj40yl3rZZcFJ/zvFMKhXVLJ5BPu161UkMpFdB/OqyYAi4ARde4CVHnVpeLL5eQrwNvoVHU0xfZWkQ@RdSrBV@f6xU/Txdra9p32anBFV8u6x0KxneEnyagM2ImjRtS22MRp/M9jS3t3AdPSOYuUHKlzUansASdruZrF3QfO6nuZEOzoaNnJhDdsTLuleuuNppyV6TYIZMj3DoxAI0SBO4HTtviJJ7Z@OhOZu05EW85Trr3UElfOskdFtb@3hx4C3zUcaJ8xtoWRRHR9jwdMbDW@Lf8eDSt97axl8DnxcGTeW0abCTd56IfnBvXu@HOR5@kQIs4VP23A/4XZjve2cmoLogmCFrq0UShzwap@C0X9NYcvwD0wtJ9DuPAzKll@4MQxcG@4vQC@Q1cAB29gUs3XOfn6eNuY87L42vsejMjFolLp7flVB@lpkOupXpWnE2Kn31xbX72FMH3XIYPKn2EB8tPojNamnRxNXtV2lW2uPYrJTuymWS8JKR48foxjA@H3w)):

```
import itertools
import random
from time import time
from functools import lru_cache

W=17 # Size of a word

# Generate a random word
def randomWord():
    return ''.join(random.choices("abcdef",k=W))

# And a random shuffling of it
def shuffle(s):
    return ''.join(random.sample(s,len(s)))

# Quick'n'dirty implementation of the function you are using
# It would have been better, btw, if you had provided them, as
# needed to create a minimal reproducible example
def findOccurrences(s, c):
    return [pos for pos, char in enumerate(s) if char == c]

def stringPop(s, i):
    return s[:i]+s[i+1:]

# Your function
def solvenaive(s1, s2, curr_ind):
    if len(s1) == 0:
        return 0
    first_s1 = s1[0]
    
    vorkommen = findOccurrences(s2, first_s1)
    results = []

    for i in vorkommen:
        new_s1 = s1[1:]
        new_s2 = stringPop(s2, i)
        res = solvenaive(new_s1, new_s2, i)
        
        if curr_ind > i:
            results.append(res+1)
        else:
            results.append(res)
    
    return min(results)

def solvenaive_memoized(s1, s2):
  @lru_cache(None)
  def solve(s1, s2, curr_ind):
    if len(s1) == 0:
        return 0
    first_s1 = s1[0]
    
    vorkommen = findOccurrences(s2, first_s1)
    results = []

    for i in vorkommen:
        new_s1 = s1[1:]
        new_s2 = stringPop(s2, i)
        res = solve(new_s1, new_s2, i)
        
        if curr_ind > i:
            results.append(res+1)
        else:
            results.append(res)
    
    return min(results)

  return solve(s1, s2, -1)


print('result original memoized ratio')
t0 = time()
while time() - t0 < 30:
  s1 = randomWord()
  s2 = shuffle(s1)
  t = time()
  r1 = solvenaive(s1, s2, -1)
  t1 = time() - t
  t = time()
  r2 = solvenaive_memoized(s1, s2)
  t2 = time() - t
  print(f'{r1} {r1 == r2} {t1:7.4f} {t2:8.4f} {round(t1 / t2):5}')
```

Comment: FYI, I added `naive_memoized` in my measurements and some observations at the end of my post.

Comment: @PierreD Yeah I saw, I'm getting aaaaaaallll the edit notifications :-). I wonder about its *slope* for `n,2`. Maybe it catches up at larger n?

Comment: Yes, the "difficulty number" (the number of possible paths) in `'abbabaaababaabbbaab'` is 1,316,818,944,000. It is the maximum possible for `n=19`: `9! * 10!`.

Comment: @PierreD 52 ms for a trillion paths ain't bad :-)

Comment: ...but 49.3 µs is better ;-)